# Limit the number of items printed on a line using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, printing

I'm just learning C#. I have the following two methods of printing the contents of a byte array. But I don't know how to limit the number of bytes to 16 per line:

```
foreach (byte i in buffer)
{
    Console.Write("{0:X2} ", i);
}
Console.WriteLine("\n");
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", buffer.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

I can use either of the above methods to complete the job. Can someone give me a suggestion for one method or the other.

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
for(int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0:X2} ", buffer[i]);
    if((i + 1) % 16 == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be "if ( (i + 1) % 16 == 0)" or it will put a single byte on the first line.

Comment: @user3389362 - Appreciate your comment. I've updated my answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Take()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb503062(v=vs.100).aspx) extension method to take at most 16 bytes from your array of bytes.

```
using System.Linq;

foreach (byte i in buffer.Take(16))
{
    Console.Write("{0:X2} ", i);
}
```

The traditional method would be to use a for loop, e.g.

```
int take = Math.Min(buffer.Length, 16);
for (int i = 0; i < take; i++)
{
    Console.Write("{0:X2} ", buffer[i]);
}
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to write all of the buffer, but only 16 bytes per line (at most), use the MoreLinq Batch() method.

```
using MoreLinq; // Install via NuGet

foreach (byte[] line in buffer.Batch(16))
{
    foreach (byte i in line)
        Console.WriteLine("{0:X2} ", i);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Yes, 16 bytes per line.

Comment: MoreLinq seems to be something I need to load from an external source. Is there a way to do this using just the Visual Studio distribution?

Comment: NuGet is fully integrated into Visual Studio.  Right-click on References for your project and select Add NuGet Reference.  MoreLinq is hugely valuable and worth getting to know (it's also created by StackOverflow's top contributer, Jon Skeet)

Comment: I'm using VS2015. I don't see "Add NuGet Reference" but do see "Add Reference" which leads to Assemblies->Extensions->NuGet.Core" so I did that but get the same error on the "using MoreLinq;" statement. The error being "error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MoreLinq' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". I also see "Manage NuGet Packages" ... so I selected that  and installed NuGet.Core but still get the error.

Comment: Sorry, it's called Manage Nuget Packages.  Was not in front of VS and wrote the name of the menu item from memory. https://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-dialog

Answer (score 1):

Using a for-loop you can take steps of 16:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i += 16)
{
    Console.WriteLine(BitConverter.ToString(bytes, i, Math.Min(16, bytes.Length - i)));
}
```

If you need to print each byte separately, use an inner-loop with a normal step of 1.

Comment: This puts a dash between each byte but I don't see why.

Comment: @user3389362 BitConverter.ToString does this automatically. It converts a byte array to a textual representation (with dashes..).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach:

```
var counter = 0;
var capacity = 16;
var str = string.Concat(buffer.Select(s =>
{
    counter++;

    var temp = string.Format("{0:X2}", s);

    if (counter < buffer.Length)
    {
        temp += ", ";
    }

    if (counter % capacity == 0)
    {
        temp += "\n";
    }

    return temp;
}));

Console.WriteLine(str);
```